# Advanced Digitizing Tools Crashing in QGIS 2.8.1 x64 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, digitizing

I'm hoping someone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong... Whenever I use the Advanced Digitizing tools in QGIS, I crash after about 5 clicks. I'm even doing it without OTF transformations on.

Any idea what's going on or if this is a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is definitely a bug, but I found a temporary fix for it...

While I was editing, I had snapping turned on. I needed this in order to snap to boundaries, measure a setback, and then start drawing my feature. I turned snapping off after my measurement line was completed, and... QGIS didn't crash! So, if anyone else runs into this issue, this worked for me

Comment: nice - did you submit to the QGIS bug trackers?

Comment: Judging from discussion on the QGIS mailing list, the cause of the crash is very likely a malfunctioning plugin rather than snapping itself.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try disabling some plugins and trying it again, but the snapping definitely seems to be an issue